# Ошибка в консоли throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ при использовании gulp

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, sass

Учусь пользоватся *gulp*, при импортировании свойств из SASS в CSS, в консоли возникает такая ошибка:

```
C:\Users\serge\Desktop\Gulp>gulp sass
[18:06:21] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Gulp\gulpfile.js
[18:06:21] Starting 'sass'...

events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: app\sass\_part.sass
Error: Invalid CSS after "    font-size:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was "25px {} }"
        on line 2 of app/sass/_part.sass
>>     font-size:25px {} }
   -------------^

    at options.error (C:\Users\serge\Desktop\Gulp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
```

Код из файла JS (подозреваю что в нём где-то ошибка):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте пробел:

```
font-size: 25px
```

Без пробела SASS воспринимает `:25px` как стейт (`:hover`) или как псевдокласс (`::before`)

Comment: Спасибо помогло, я почему-то не подумал что пробелы принципиальны в коде )